# Period of time between salaries

Tags: translation

In Russia we receieve a salary every month, not every week or something. Usually, it's not the first day of a month when we get paid, it can be every 5th or every 25th day of a month.

So, period between the first and the last day of the month is actually called “month” in English. What about period between salaries, e.g. 25th January — 25th February? Is it “accounting month”, “paying month”, “reporting month” or something?

In case you know Russian, I mean the translation of “отчетный месяц”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vadim, there are two issues involved- at least in America. There is the period when your time is recorded for which you are paid. However, you don't get paid immediately on the last day of that period. There is usually a lag time lasting a week to two weeks. It may be even more.

No matter how long it is, the periods for which your time is recorded and for which you get paid are called "pay period". This is also the case in any field where "period" can be used to define any span of time from one date to the next date. Therefore, the period between salary/paycheck/disbursement is a salary period, paycheck period, or disbursement period, respectively.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I'm ok with _pay period_, but I need to make it even more explicit, I want to use _month_ word. Can I say _pay month_?

Comment: @VadimPushtaev - But what if it's not a month?  Most people in the US get paid every two weeks, not every month.  If the period is really a month, and you want to call it "a month", why not just say "a month"?  I guess you could say "monthly pay period" if you want to emphasize both concepts.

Comment: Waite, I have to edit my original response ...

Comment: Vadim, if you only have one of them per month, even if the time between them i snot necessarily a month, you could just say "monthly salary period"- which would be the period between the dates each month when you get your check.

Comment: http://fbs.admin.utah.edu/news/2015/02/11/accounting-month-is-closed/ "accounting mongth" seems ok, right?

Comment: @VadimPushtaev in the English-speaking world, the word "accounting" relates to business financial transactions and is not related to employee pay. I am a financial analyst and when I worked at a large company, our accounting period was always the 27th of one month to the 26th of the next month- always. Accounts (from company ledger) were closed on the 26th and all accounts reconciled, etc. Employee pay does not fall into that cycle.

Comment: Do you call it "accounting month"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it". We use "accounting period" for the span of time between the 27th of March to the 26th of April. However, we would say "accounting month" when we refer to April 2015 as to denote the closing of accounts that month. So "accounting month" April 2015 was during "accounting period" 3/272015 (period begin date) to 4/26/2015 (period end date). However, "accounting month" has no meaning for most people other than business people, analysts, accountants, and some other professionals. Most Americans would have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 2):

I'd ***still*** call it as 'Monthly salary'. That's because *no matter* when, the gap is 30/31 days that denotes one month.

We often refer to magazines, letters, tasks 'monthly' that happens every month, not necessarily on 1st day. Monthly means between two dates, the gap is of 30/31 days.

When we say 'monthly salary', it means *once in a month*.

**About the terms,** there could be many - **pay period, monthly interval, payment interval** and so on. [Refer to this document of **Washington State Legislature**](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=296-126-023). It's very useful.

Comment: Do you mean _period_ is called _salary_? No way, how could it?

Comment: updated. Check out the new answer

Comment: That is a good source, but keep in mind that governments do this to establish nomenclature and ease communication by creating standards. It has a specific context. (For example notice they use "interval" instead of "period" because "monthly period" has gynecological references.) Or for example the Government of Canada that uses "governor general" instead of 'governor-general", and enacted this in an act of parliament. However, there is usually an parallel and more general standard.